# Обновление скриптов TypeScript на клиенте

Tags: typescript, javascript

Работаю сейчас с кодом на TypeScript. Вопрос такой: как обновить эти скрипты на клиенте?

Насчет обычных js-скриптов нашел советы ссылки делать так: `file.js?10122014`. Логично, вроде, и дата обновления есть, и скрипты обновятся. Вот только с TypeScript как такое сделать, не могу представить. Прямых ссылок в проекте нет, нашел только указания на папки со скриптами. Настроек компилятора нужных пока не нашел.

Может, кто работал с TypeScript и подскажет. Не верю, что способа нет, но мне его найти пока не удалось.

Comment: Typescript должен транспилироваться в джаваскрипт где-то в вашем проект, и эти файлы подтягиваются клиентом. На них можно повесить таймстамп в точно такой же манере. Чем собирается проект?

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать встроенный в TypeScript сборщик бандла, то можно так же как с обычным javascript.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES3",
        "module": "amd",
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom"
        ],
        "typeRoots" : [
            "./src/types",
            "./dto/*"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "build": [ "./build" ],
            "dto": [ "./dto" ]
        },
        "outFile": "./build/client.js",
        "rootDir": "./src/" 
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>

        <script src="./assets/js/react.development.js"></script>    
        <script src="./assets/js/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/js/redux.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/js/react-redux.min.js"></script>

        <!-- GET параметр для предотвращения кеширования -->
        <script src="./build/client.js?10122014"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mount-point"></div>
        <script>Testing.Main();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```